# Read only PDF after form has filled - Adobe Life Cycle Designer

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, readonly, acrobat

I have a PDF form, which users can fill. After filling the PDF they can save the PDF and submit that PDF to me.

Acrobat don't allow the PDF to save on the main PDF. So users need to save it separately. But that separate PDF is also editable. Is there any way, that user can fill information only once. Once they save the PDF, no one can change that form information.

It should become Read only after that. Is there some script or any way this can be achieved.

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong, but I think you can use Document Actions with XFA forms.

If so, you could set all your fields to readonly in the willSave action.

Answer (score -1):

That's how I sorted this.
I just got two PDF readers installed on my box - Acrobat Reader and Foxit Reader.

1. I open editable form in Acrobat Reader.
2. Click 'File'->'Print'
3. On a popup window I pick 'Foxit Reader PDF Printer' as my Printer.
4. Click 'Print' and save file.
5. Now your newly created file is read-only! And it is still formatted text, not an image!